# Webserver with timer for home automation light

Tags: html, raspberry-pi

Sitting with my Raspberry Pi trying to create a webserver with an integrated timer for 8 channels.

At the moment I've created a server where I can click "on/off" for the light.

What I'm looking for:

A simple test webpage with a textarea to write how many seconds the light should be turned on. This number should be printed into a specific line in a text document.

The number should be placed like this:
gpio write 13 1
sleep"number here"
gpio wirte 13 0

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input id="whiteElephant" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">

    <script>
    var myInput=document.getElementById("whiteElephant");//element to be changed by user
    myInput.setAttribute('onchange', 'doSomething(this)');//when this element is changed it fires a function

    function doSomething(input){
    var myVariable="gpio write 13 1 sleep" + input.value + "gpio wirte 13 0";//set myVariable to the string that is required
    //do something with myVariable
    }
    </script>
```